# Help with non-linear system of equations

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

This system of equations

$$\begin{align} xy+yz+zx & =3 \\ \\
x^4+y^4+z^4 & =3\end{align}$$

How to solve this system of equations?

Any help, Plz.

Thank all

Comment: Are you looking for solutions in integers, rationals, reals or complex numbers?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you are solving over the reals.

$1 =  \sqrt[4]{ \frac{x^4 + y^4 + z^4} {3}} $  $\geq \sqrt { \frac {x^2 + y^2 + z^2 } { 3}} \geq \sqrt{ \frac{ |xy| + |yz| + |xz| } { 3} } \geq \sqrt{ \frac{ xy+yz+zx} { 3}} = 1$

These inequalities are standard.
The first one is power mean applied to fourth powers and second powers.
The second one is $(|x|-|y|)^2+(|y|-|z|)^2+(|z|-|x|)^2 \geq 0$.
The third one follows from the definition of absolute value / triangle inequality.

Hence equality must hold throughout, so $|x|=|y|=|z|=1$.

A further check shows that $xy+yz+zx = 3$ if and only if $x, y, z$ have the same sign. Thus, we have $x=y=z=1, x=y=z=-1$.

Note: As mentioned, the motivation is that the solution set is one where all variables are equal, suggesting that some kind of inequality can be shown to hold, which gives us the equality condition (which is that all variables are equal).

---

If you are solving over the complex numbers, I believe there are many solutions.

Comment: +$1$: Good answer!

Comment: @Clayton Thanks! I threw in the absolute signs on the off chance that happens :)

Comment: How would you suggest the question be tagged, Calvin? (+1 btw)

Comment: It should be system of equations. This is a standard trick used in olympiad problems, where you convert to inequalities and force the equality condition.

Comment: It's really strange that there's no such tag, though there's one for diophantine which arguably is a more specialized set. In my personal tags, i use "system of linear equation" and "system of equations"(for non-linear)

Comment: (+1) I created a systems-of-equations tag. See [this metathread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10006/11619) for a discussion. It is not at all clear that the tag will survive in this form. You're welcome to participate in its evolution!

Comment: @Calvin Lin: Thank you :)